# /etc/init.d/netfs equivalent RHEL 7

Tags: rhel7, netfs

I just migrated from RHEL 6 to RHEL 7. I used to call the following in order to list active NFS mounts:

```
/etc/init.d/netfs status
```

That would provide this kind of output:

```
Configured NFS mountpoints: 
/data
Active NFS mountpoints: 
/data
```

Since RHEL 7 doesn't use this script anymore, could you please let me know what the equivalent would be? (if there is one)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command :

```
mount -l | grep nfs
```

Another way :

```
cat /proc/mounts | grep nfs
```

Also this command is used to get more information about the mountpoints :

```
nfsstat
```